# Parse Json from Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been trying to integrate with Facebook SDK to login then get the user's data. so I'm using this method after authentication to get the user's details.

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
         }
     }];
}
```

And the data I'm getting is :

```
2015-07-08 14:02:40.502 Auth-App[whatever] fetched user:{
    "first_name" = Lol;
    gender = male;
    id = 12345;
    "last_name" = Ak;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/...../....";
    locale = "en_US";
    name = "Lol Ak";
    timezone = 4;
    "updated_time" = "2015-07-08T10:22:32+0000";
    verified = 1;
}
```

i need to read this array and then display it in text fields.
i tried using results[0] to get the first element in the array but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way to access data from dictionary

```
NSLog("%@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]);
NSLog("%@",[result objectForKey:@"first_name"]);
NSLog("%@",[result objectForKey:@"name"]);
```

same as read all the fields(key/value) pairs. And set your textFields

Comment: Okey great , but it returns : `id=12345` , how is it possible to get the number only ? without `id=` ?

Comment: NSLog("%@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]); try this way. just "id=" label @NataMio

Answer (score 0):

Please put two lines your code

```
NSDictionary *array=[request.responseString JSONValue];
yourtextfield.text=[array valueForKey:@"first_name"];
```

Comment: i don't have such a request.responceString in my code ?